# mvc post action json is not parsed to arguments

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, gridview

I Have action in controler:

```
[POST]
public JsonResult ApproveOrders(Guid[] ordersIdToApprove)
{
    [...]
    return Json(dataToReturn);
}
```

And i'm trying to call it from the view via javasrcript:

```
function ApproveAllClicked(e, c) {
var url = $("#ApproveButton").data("url");

var data = { ordersIdToApprove: DataGrid.GetSelectedKeysOnPage() };
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'application/json'
    });
}
```

DataGrid.GetSelectedKeysOnPage() is mechanism from Devexpress Mvc GridView. It return id's of all selected rows in grid in this format:

```
["3a19f538-0cf6-e311-93f5-000c2948090b", "71021f74-f308-e411-93f5-000c2948090b"]
```

Action in controller is called, but array from argument is empty. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to breakpoint your return statement to see if any data is actually in your "dataToReturn" variable?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your ajax call or your action method, I've just tested them with hard-coded data & it all works ok. Can you debug the `DataGrid.GetSelectedKeysOnPage()` function on the js console & see what it's returning?

Comment: @markpsmith -guids in my post are actual data received from the DataGrid.GetSelectedKeysOnPage().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you ajax options, add

```
traditional: true,
```

If this is not set, then

```
items : ["A", "B"]
```

will be posted as

```
items[]=A&items[]=B
```

instead of

```
items=A&items=B
```